# Remove :valid pseudo class from inputs with Javsacript

Tags: javascript, validation, bootstrap-4

I have a form with multiple sections. Each section is validated manually using Bootstrap 4 validation (without submitting the form for real). This works fine with the code below;

```
let eventCreationForm = $(".event-creation-form");
if (!eventCreationForm[0].checkValidity()) {
    eventCreationForm.find(":submit").click();
}
```

However, I only want to highlight the inputs that are invalid. I.e, don't highlight valid inputs in green. Rather than overwrite the bootstrap styles for this, I figured I would try and remove the `:valid` pseudo class from the valid inputs. However, I can't find any examples of anybody doing this. The questions I've looked through on SO just change the styles via CSS.

I thought something like this might work,
`eventCreationForm.find(":valid").removeClass(":valid");` but I suppose it doesn't as it's not a real class.

The example below has a callstack error, but that's just this example.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        }
        form.classList.add('was-validated');
      }, false);
    });
    
    $(".manual-submit").click(function(){
      let eventCreationForm = $(".event-creation-form");
      if (!eventCreationForm[0].checkValidity()) {
        eventCreationForm.find(":submit").click();
      }
    })
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form class="needs-validation event-creation-form" novalidate>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
      <label for="validationCustom01">First name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom01" placeholder="First name" value="Mark" required>
      <div class="valid-feedback">
        Looks good!
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
      <label for="validationCustomUsername">Username</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupPrepend">@</span>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustomUsername" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend" required>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          Please choose a username.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary manual-submit">Submit form</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot get rid of the `:valid` pseudo-class at all as far as I know.

However, the problem here isn't those pseudo-classes. Bootstrap 4 will behave as asked in the question when the `was-validated` class is *NOT* added to the form, as long as you manually add the `is-invalid` class where appropriate.

As per the [Bootstrap 4 documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#validation):

> As a fallback, .is-invalid and .is-valid classes may be used instead of the pseudo-classes for server side validation. *They do not require a .was-validated parent class.*

(Emphasis mine.)

The reason you're seeing the `:valid` and `:invalid` pseudo-classes styled is because of the `was-validated` class on the parent:

> Bootstrap scopes the :invalid and :valid styles to parent .was-validated class, usually applied to the <form>. Otherwise, any required field without a value shows up as invalid on page load. This way, you may choose when to activate them (typically after form submission is attempted).

Comment: Under those circumstances, wouldn’t there be no outline at all? I wanted to keep the red invalid ones a hide the green ones.

Comment: I've made an edit to clarify. The `is-valid` and `is-invalid` classes don't require the use of `was-validated`. In fact, `was-validated` is the reason `:valid` and `:invalid` are getting styled. Of course, you'll need to use the `is-valid` and `is-invalid` classes. You could sync the `is-invalid` class to the `:invalid` pseudo-class.

Answer (score 4):

You can actually toggle the `:valid` and `:invalid` pseudo-classes indirectly with `setCustomValidity()` in JavaScript.

From the [Bootstrap 4 documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#how-it-works) (also works in Bootstrap 5):

> You may provide custom validity messages with setCustomValidity in JavaScript.

To add `:invalid` and remove `:valid`, use:

```
var error = "An invalid input message.";
this.setCustomValidity(error);
```

To add `:valid` and remove `:invalid`, use:

```
this.setCustomValidity("");
```

You can also add, remove, or change the error message by manipulating the text in the appropriate element.