# How to disable bootstrap 4 validation style from valid controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap 4 styling for my application. Application has two text boxes and one submit button. When you click the "Save" button it will call a web API and get some details asynchronously(it will not redirect the page).
Validation applied for the first text box only.

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        }
        form.classList.add('was-validated');
      }, false);
    });
  }, false);
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Test Page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form class="container needs-validation" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group row mt-5">
      <label for="txtSessionDescription" class="col-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your name" required />
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          Please enter the name.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row mt-5">
      <label for="txtSessionDescription" class="col-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-form-label">Address:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="tel" class="form-control" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 100px;" value="Save" />
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

**My problem:**

When I click the "Save" button without entering any values to the text boxes, green color style(validation true style) is applying to the "Address" textbox. I don't wont that to happen.

I only need red color style(validation failed style) to be applied if the validation is failed. If the values are entered(validation is true), I don't need any styling to be applied to the text boxes.

Also when I enter some value to the "Name" text box and click the "Save" button, I don't want green color styling for that text box.

**Screenshot:**

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I, for one, do not like overriding the CSS style so you could also choose to just specify which fields to validate instead of the entire form.

Add a class to your `.form-group` element (e.g. `.validate-me`)

```
    <form class="container needs-validation" novalidate>
        <div class="form-group row mt-5 validate-me">
            <label for="txtSessionDescription" class="col-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your name" required />
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    Please enter the name.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row mt-5">
            <label for="txtSessionDescription" class="col-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-form-label">Address:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="tel" class="form-control" formnovalidate="formnovalidate" id="address" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 100px;" value="Save"/>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Now change your JavaScript slightly, retrieve all the `form-group`s with the `validate-me` class and instead of calling `form.classList.add('was-validated')` loop through all the captured form-groups and add `was-validated` to them instead.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
                // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
                var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');

                // Get all form-groups in need of validation
                var validateGroup = document.getElementsByClassName('validate-me');

                // Loop over them and prevent submission
                var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function (form) {
                    form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
                        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            event.stopPropagation();
                        }

                        //Added validation class to all form-groups in need of validation
                        for (var i = 0; i < validateGroup.length; i++) {
                            validateGroup[i].classList.add('was-validated');
                        }
                    }, false);
                });
            }, false);
```

Comment: I don't think this provides an answer to the question. This lets you choose which fields to validate, while the question was about disabling the valid styles for all fields.

Answer (score 6):

You might want to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55591707/6548555).

Specifically, instead of adding `.was-validated` to the entire form, only add `.is-invalid` to the form elements which have the `:invalid` pseudo-class.

This code should work in your case:

```
for (var i = 0; i < validateGroup.length; i++) {
    var invalidGroup = validateGroup[i].querySelectorAll(":invalid");
    for (var j = 0; j < invalidGroup.length; j++) {
        invalidGroup[j].classList.add('is-invalid');
    }
}
```

Comment: This is how I accomplished this as well. However, I attached an event listener to each invalid field to remove the "is-invalid" class if the value is changed. This allows the user to update an invalid field and resubmit.

`invalidGroup[j].addEventListener("input", e => e.target.classList.remove("is-invalid"), { once: true });`

Answer (score 5):

You can override css of the is-valid validation. When you right click on the green check box and choose inspect you can see which class is causing the green light

[image]
So you should specify to not inherit those from bootstrap. The code should be like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .form-control.is-valid:focus, .was-validated :valid.form-control{ border-color:inherit !important;
    background-image: inherit !important;
    box-shadow:inherit !important;}

 </style>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function () {
            'use strict';
            window.addEventListener('load', function () {
                // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
                var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
                // Loop over them and prevent submission
                var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function (form) {
                    form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
                        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            event.stopPropagation();
                        }
                        form.classList.add('was-validated');
                    }, false);
                });
            }, false);
        })();
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form class="container needs-validation" novalidate id="myFrom" >
        <div class="form-group row mt-5">
            <label for="txtSessionDescription" class="col-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your name" required />
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    Please enter the name.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row mt-5">
            <label for="txtSessionDescription" class="col-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-form-label">Address:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="tel" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 100px;" value="Save"/>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

What I added is the style tag and css options below the head tag.

Comment: This works, I didn't understand why you unaccepted the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Override the `$form-validation-states` scss variable. This is documented in Bootstrap 5 but the same technique applies to version 4.

https://v5.getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/validation/#customizing

```
$form-validation-states: (
  "valid": (                               <-- delete this
    "color": $form-feedback-valid-color,
    "icon": $form-feedback-icon-valid
  ),
  "invalid": (
    "color": $form-feedback-invalid-color,
    "icon": $form-feedback-icon-invalid
  )
);
```

Comment: Somehow, this does not compile for me.

Comment: This solution only works in Bootstrap 5, it will not compile in version 4. More information: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/29007#issuecomment-521251987

Using map-remove seems to be the only way to remove the valid state in Bootstrap 4:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/theming/#remove-from-map
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/30141

Answer (score 2):

```
  (function () {
    'use strict';
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        const forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
        Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function (form) {
            form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
                if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.stopPropagation();
                }
                const invalidGroup = form.querySelectorAll(":invalid");
                for (let j = 0; j < invalidGroup.length; j++) {
                    invalidGroup[j].classList.add('is-invalid');
                }
            }, false);
        });
    }, false);
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

The post from @Ilker Kadir Ozturk worked for me by just using style, except that my valid field border inherited from a prior color (Black) which I did not want to use.  I am using Bootstrap 4 and ASP.NET MVC in a razor page.   Here is his code adjusted with my color (#DDDDDD). I included my comments also above the styles :

```
 @*  This is to prevent the green color style on Bootstrap validation to be applied to all textboxes when the info is valid.
    Only the red color style(validation failed style) should be applied if the validation failed.
    If the values are ok, no styling should be applied to the text boxes.
    Also when the "submit" button is clicked, there is no need for the green color styling to show up either.
 *@

<style>
    .form-control.is-valid:focus, .was-validated :valid.form-control {
        border-color: #DDDDDD !important;
        background-image: inherit !important;
        box-shadow: inherit !important;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

### A partial Solution to Remove Styling In Case Validation Was Successful

If `form.checkValidity()` evaluates true, remove `was-validated` class from the form.

---

An example in **React Bootstrap**:

Having `<Form noValidate validated={this.state.validated} onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>`

```
onSubmit = (e) => this.setState({ validated: !e.currentTarget.checkValidity()});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to a similar problem using jQuery:

In your submit method, insert the following lines after calling `checkValidity()`:

```js
$("#myForm").find(":valid").parent().removeClass("was-validated"); // Optional: Removes all green borders that have been fixed since last submit attempt
$("#myForm").removeClass("needs-validation");
$("#myForm").find(":invalid").parent().addClass("was-validated");
```

This solution only adds red borders to invalid inputs. Once they have been corrected, though, they will be displayed with a green border, but personally, I still prefer this over a forest of green fields if only one input is invalid ...

Answer (score 0):

I would like to summarize this using an example. This one includes:

1. Validations for some fields you need adding class value
   "validate-me"
2. Remove the green validation style
3. Refresh the invalid validation

This example will contain three html inputs:

[image]

the html code for this example is:

```
<form class="needs-validation "  novalidate>

    <div class="validate-me">
        <label for="firstNameId">First name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstNameId" required>
        
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Please provide a first name.
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="">
        <label for="miId">MI</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="miId"  required>
        
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Please provide a MI name.
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="validate-me">
        <label for="lastNameId">Last name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastNameId" required>
        
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Please provide a last name.
        </div>
    </div>
 ...
</form>
```

For validation, include the following js function:

```
(function () {
     'use strict';
      window.addEventListener('load', function () {
       // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
       var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');

      // Get all form-groups in need of validation
       var validateGroup = document.getElementsByClassName('validate-me');

     // Loop over them and prevent submission
       var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function (form) {
                                    form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
      if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
         event.preventDefault();
         event.stopPropagation();
      }
           //Added validation class to diva in need of validation
     
         for (var i = 0; i < validateGroup.length; i++) {
             var invalidGroup = validateGroup[i].querySelectorAll(":invalid");
             for (var j = 0; j < invalidGroup.length; j++) {
                   invalidGroup[j].classList.add('is-invalid');
                   invalidGroup[j].addEventListener("input", e => e.target.classList.remove("is-invalid"), { once: true });
             }
        }
     }, false);
  });
}, false);
```

Therefore, the validation will be applied just to fields that have class value: "validate-me", green validation will be removed and the red invalid message will be auto refreshed.

[image]

Example with no green validation:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (Bootstrap 5.3)

```scss
// ...

// 4. Include any default map overrides here
$form-validation-states: map-remove($form-validation-states, "valid");

// 5. Include remainder of required parts
@import "bootstrap/scss/maps";

// ...
```

[Remove from map doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/sass/#remove-from-map)