# boostrap 4.3.1 remove input validation class with jquery

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I would like to clean a modal form after closing.
I use html input required validation

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="smtp_user" placeholder="" required>
```

In previous versions of bootstrap I did it this way

```
$( form ).find( ':input' ).val( '' ).prop( 'selectedIndex', 0 ).removeClass( 'invalid' );
```

Now this procedure does not seem to work because when I re-open my modal form I find the highlighted error fields.
I also tried to use

```
removeClass( ':invalid' );
```

but without success.

Can anyone tell me where I'm wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove :valid pseudo class from inputs with Javsacript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55493103/remove-valid-pseudo-class-from-inputs-with-javsacript)

Comment: I had pretty much the same question (^) a few months ago and didn't get very far, unfortunately. You might have a couple more options though - have you tried removing the 'was-validated' class from the form?

Comment: @Lewis - unfortunately I tried and it doesn't work.